# How to totally suppress Git Clone output?

Tags: git, shell

I am writing a shell script wherein I am doing

```
log=/var/tmp/git_prod_test_pack/log.out
Time_clone=`(/usr/bin/time -f'%e' git clone --quiet ssh://id@xxxxxxxxxx) 2>&1 >> $log`
echo $Time_clone
```

It is giving output as
Total 104 (delta 0), reused 104 (delta 0) 0.17

How can I totally suppress this output and get only 0.17 ?

Comment: I can't reproduce it; I'm getting the time as output, and empty `log.out` file (because of `--quiet` switch). Can you give us some more info about your environment? What OS, shell type and version (sh/bash/zsh etc.) and git version are you using?

Comment: Linux XXXXXXX 2.6.18-348.el5 #1 SMP Wed Nov 28 21:22:00 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux , using bash

Comment: git version 1.8.2.1

Answer (score 5):

`git clone --quiet https://github.com/dask/dask.git` does not produce any output unless you have errors. Your code should work fine, unless you have some bug in the (older) git you use or some weird config of your shell.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this but yes, `git clone --quiet` combined with the `--branch` option pointing to a tag _does_ produce output. It gives the typical "detached HEAD state" informative message. Unfortunately this gets printed to stderr so you can't get rid of it without also getting rid of actual errors.

Comment: @Quintesse fair enough, but the question did not mention using --branch